# Relative path in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, path, telerik

I'm trying to use a relative path to consume a Web Service from Silverlight but I have to use the full Path of the service (this service is working in the same web that has the xap file) and I want to use a relative path to make it work both in local and server.

This is working in a older version of the same Project so I think I've changed something in my project settings...

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Example Code I'm using:

```
<telerik:ReportViewer x:Name="Reportviewer1"
                               ReportServiceUri="http://localhost:11951/ReportService.svc"
```

I want this to work like this:

```
<telerik:ReportViewer x:Name="Reportviewer1"
                               ReportServiceUri="./ReportService.svc"
```

Comment: Coudl you show the code that isn't working, and what you think the path should be.

Comment: Run you app under Google Chrome and check Network tab in Develper Tools. Which http query was created to get ReportService.svc?, wheen you use relative path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.

If you start your silverlight project from the asp.net project that contains it, relative paths work fine, but if you start the project with the silverlight project you can't use relative paths...